# Specifying inheritance in WCF XmlSchema

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, xsd, ixmlserializable

I'm faced with a situation where I have to implement IXmlSerializable on a datatype, which I'll send through WCF service. But when I try to mark the base class in the xsd, the service reference can no longer be refreshed, and the type I'm writing the xsd for "cannot be found".
Here is the xsd:

```
<xs:schema 
xmlns:tnsg="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNS" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNS" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:base="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BaseNS">
  <xs:complexType name="MyType">
    <xs:extension base="base:BaseType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="BProperties">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BInfo" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="AProperties">
                <xs:complexType >
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AStuff" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="MyType" nillable="true" type="MyType" />
</xs:schema>"
```

Here is the C#:

```
public static XmlQualifiedName GetMySchema(XmlSchemaSet xs)
{
   XmlSchema s =  XmlSchema.Read(new StringReader(xsd), (sender, eargs) => {  });
   xs.Add(s);
   return new XmlQualifiedName("MyType", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNS");
}
```

I assume I need to import BaseType somehow?

EDIT:
I've tried

```
  var baseschemes = xs.Schemas("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyBase");
  foreach (XmlSchema item in baseschemes)
  {
      s.Includes.Add(item);
  }
```

it adds one schema (as expected), but nothing changes!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your current WSDL isn't telling the client where to find a schema with a targetNamespace of "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BaseNS". You should either include another  element into your WSDL that contains the full schema for this namespace, or provide a  that references an static XSD with it.

Comment: How to provide a static XSD? My BaseType is a simple DataContract class, I've written no XSD for it. Can I export it? Can I load it from the XmlSchemaSet?

Comment: See original post pls for my new (unsuccessful) ideas

Comment: WCF couldn't possibly export it on its own; since you're using IXmlSerializable, it has no way of knowing you cared about that base type at all.

Comment: I think you should be able to use XsdDataContractExporter to generate the required schema, though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.xsddatacontractexporter.aspx

Comment: With calling xs.Schemas(...) on the XmlSchemaSet I was able to find the already generated schema for my BaseType, but I couldn't add it to the current schema (kept getting exceptions). How do I add it to the current? s.Includes.Add(schema) + <xs:include />? No combination seemed to work!